# Understanding concurrency management in .NET

Tags: .net, concurrency

I have a few reference variables that will see potentially high concurrency in reads and that will need to be updated once in a while. Do writes need to be synched with reads and how can it be achieved efficiently?

Comment: `ReaderWriterLock`?

Comment: Do you mind stale or malformed reads? If those are unacceptable then yes writes need to be synced with reads. Otherwise, you can get away without locking.

Comment: As others indicated, this question has little to do with .NET, but more of a general question at operating system level, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers–writer_lock `ReaderWriterLock` or better `ReaderWriterLockSlim` should be the class you explore.

Comment: @580, by malformed you mean reading something that is not the prev value and is not the latest one? Can read operations concurrent to a write lead to reading a value that is not the old one and neither the new one? Is this true for value types only or also for reference types? In the case of a reference type I would only be writing/changing the pointer/reference, would I?

Comment: "Can read operations concurrent to a write lead to reading a value that is not the old one and neither the new one?" Yes. If the operation is not atomic this is exactly what can and probably will happen. Additionally, if you're using a collection or some other non-thread safe object you may get exceptions thrown as well.

Comment: "Is this true for value types only or also for reference types?" It depends on what data is being modified. On a 32-bit operating system a 64-bit integer modification is not atomic and you can get what is known as "tearing". I would be inclined to say that any reference type will be subject to the same issue. With the only exception being a reference type that is somehow modified within one clock cycle / instruction.

Comment: "In the case of a reference type I would only be writing/changing the pointer/reference, would I? " Well that depends. If you're creating a whole new object then reassigning the variable to that new object technically yes you're just updating the reference. So then your issue would be how is that object being created, is that done in a thread safe manner? If you were to just be modifying properties (or public fields) of an object you'll once again be subject to tearing.

Comment: That all being said I think the [ReaderWriterLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx) as already pointed out by @PetSerAl is sufficient for most everything. Are you worried about performance? What is the reasoning behind not wanting to sync? I'm going to be gone for a bit so don't expect an immediate reply after this one.

Comment: @580 I'm not sure I understood. I have a collection that will need to be recreated with updated values once in a while. I'll be creating the new collection separately and when ready, will update the reference variable read threads are using to access the collection. In this situation does updating the reference variable need to be guarded?

Comment: What collection type is being used? What is being stored in the collection, sounds like a user defined class? Is this new collection created and modified by a single thread? Most importantly, once this new collection is assigned to the variable read threads use will it be modified or will you always recreate (and assign) an entirely new collection for all modifications?

Comment: One publisher, many consumers and consumers don't change anything. I'm not sure I'm following you, what difference does it make the specific type of collection with the fact that updating a reference variable to point to a different instance is or not an atomic operation?

Comment: Reference types are guaranteed by the C# standard to be atomic; on all platforms. Therefore, if all you're doing is reassigning a collection you're not going to have any "malforming" issues. You'll still have stale reads to deal with. The reason I ask so many questions is typically because premature optimization can be (is) evil. That and no locking multi-threading can be complex. I do my best to avoid giving advice on complex topics until I get a really good idea about what is being done. Hence the plethora of questions. Sorry for the late reply I wasn't notified of your update.

Comment: Be sure to create the new collections in a thread-safe manner before the "re-assignment". If this is an acceptable response let me know, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @noplace let me know if you have any other concerns with this scenario